# Gulp task is running in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a gulp task to copy all html files from source to destination.

**html gulp task**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
module.exports = function() {
    return gulp.src('./client2/angularts/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client2/script/src/'));
 };
```

and gulp watch which start running whenever I change .Html file it swill start html gulp task.

**watch.ts**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var  sq   = require('run-sequence');
module.exports = function () {

    var tsClientHtml = [
        'client2/**/*.html'
    ];



    watch(tsClientHtml, function () {
        gulp.run('html');
    });

};
```

Its going in infinite loop, means whenever I am changing in html file its ruining html gulp task again and again...
Can someone please suggest what is wrong in this watch.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are watching the dest folder. Try changing tsClientHtml to `'./client2/angularts/**/*.html'`.